# Turning a String[] into an int[] and then the int[] into separate variables (x, y, z)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, methods, integer

I am new to programming and have decided to take the steps towards learning C# and while working through certain tutorials, books, and other guides, I came across the StreamReader command.

As my way of learning has been to play with new commands I find interesting, i decided to just dig my way through the command and see what I could do.

Which leads to the question, I have my code here that does what I want it to.

It takes the line from the file, turns it into a string array, proceeds to turn that into a int array and then i classify each part of the array in a variable to be used in the main section of code.

What I want to know is is there a cleaner way to do just this?
When I include a second, thirst, etc... line pulled from the file, will I be able to use my Turner method(?) to repeat this process?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StreamReaderToIntArray
{
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 0;

            string[] stringSeperators = new string[] { " " };

            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt");
            string line = myReader.ReadLine();
            var myArray = line.Split(stringSeperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            myReader.Close();

            Turner(myArray, out x, out y, out z);
        }

        static private int Turner(string[] newArray, out int x, out int y, out int z)
        {
           int[] cArray = newArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

           x = cArray[0];
           y = cArray[1];
           z = cArray[2];


            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you directly assign `x`, `y` and `z` from the string array like `x = Int32.Parse(newArray[0])`?

Comment: It is always good idea to read first several pages of tutorial for language you are trying to learn. I bet it would say something about repeating operations...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I'm not quite sure why I didn't just directly assign it and parse there. Good question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've read over repeating operations and in this bit of code had not yet included them. I had been focused on getting it to do what I wanted first before getting it to do what I wanted multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see is that `int.Parse()` throws an exception if it does not like the input. Also you never check to see if the line actually contains 3 values. I don't like using `out` for three values, when they can be combined into a single `struct Point { int x,y,z; }` and returning that from the function.

So I suggest creating an [Extension Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) for the parsing using `int.TryParse()` and returning an integer array the same size as the string array.

```
{
    string line = myReader.ReadLine();
    var point = Point.Parse(line);
}

public struct Point
{
    readonly int x, y, z;  // Always make struct immutable
    public Point(int x,int y,int z)
    {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.z = z;
    }

    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }
    public int Z { get { return z; } }

    public static Point Parse(string line)
    {
      var parts = line.Split(stringSeperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      var array = parts.Select( (s)=> s.ParseInt() ).ToArray();
      if(array.Length>=3) 
      {
          return new Point(array[0],array[1],array[2]);
      }      
      throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
}

// Example extensions for parsing strings
public static class Extensions
{
    public int ParseInt(this string value)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int.TryParse(value, out x);
        return x;
    }
    public float ParseFloat(this string value)
    {
        float x = 0;
        float.TryParse(value, out x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I stated, I am new to programming. Meaning brand spanking new as of three days ago. So, syntax like    `Int.TryParse()`was unknown to me and i'll look into it currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that the text file contains one line with three numbers separated by one or more spaces, then this code works:

```
int[] values =
    File
        .ReadAllText("Values.txt")
        .Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToArray();

int x = values[0];
int y = values[1];
int z = values[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case instead of using `StreamReader` try `File.ReadAllLines` [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    string[] stringSeperators = new string[] { " " };

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Values.txt");
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
       string[] myArray = line.Split(stringSeperators,
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       Turner(myArray, out x, out y, out z); 
    }       
}
```

But with this approach variables `x, y, z` will keep only values of last line.
Consider using @ja72's `struct` for keeping values and create a `List` or `Array` of values